Automating Jenkins Pipeline Creation and Configuration Updates
I have multiple pipelines that I need to update each time the version of my program changes. Is it possible to create Jenkins pipelines (instead of clicking + New Item in UI) or update them (for example which branch or tag to use, or time of execution) using another main pipeline. Otherwise every time something changes I have to go through each pipeline and click on Configure and update it manually.

Givin' a very brief picture is using Jenkins job builder (a.k.a, JJB), and in your yaml file you can switch repo_branch: master to repo_branch: <feature-branch>. Afterwards you can apply the branch changes using jenkins-jobs --conf <your conf.ini> update configs/your_job_.yaml:configs/defaults.yaml, This could be useful in your case. However, adopting JJB into your pipeline requires more investigation.

Can that change be parameterized?

This looks to me the same as the issue here : How to modify a Jenkins pipeline job's property programmatically.
Summary

You can either use Jenkinsfile ; this would require efforts but it's better in the long run, or you can use Jenkins API/CLI to get/update job configuration, with some kind of wrapper either Bash or Python to update your config.xml with your changes.


You can invoke a pipeline with parameters in a step, in a stage, of your main pipeline. Here is an example from another answer:
pipeline {
    agent
    {
        node {
                label 'master'
                customWorkspace "${env.JobPath}"
              }
    }

    stages 
    {
        stage('Start') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }

        stage ('Invoke_pipeline') {
            steps {
                build job: 'pipeline1', parameters: [
                string(name: 'param1', value: "value1")
                ]
            }
        }

        stage('End') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
}

You can then use build parameters to pass data to a Jenkins job, and if needed parametrize it manually from a web interface. See these screenshots from this Baeldung guide.


